# How to toggle jQuery element with a duration AND display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

When I want to toggle **off** a component I can use

```
$("#donkey").toggle(false);
```

and when I need it to be toggled during a certain time period I can use

```
$("#emailInvalid").toggle(700);
```

but now I'd like to combine those two. I want to ensure that the component is being toggled **off** (not only toggled back and forth) and I want to specify a duration of the process.

According to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-options), I'm supposed to be able to specify an object with options, too. However, the following

```
$("#donkey").toggle({ duration: 700, display: false });
```

only toggles the donkey back and forth (during said time, though), whereas I'd like it to be toggled to invisibility. When I reviewed the options, I noticed that there's none that addresses *display*, so I fear that the above is treated by jQuery equivalently with

```
$("#donkey").toggle({ duration: 700, biteMe: "in the donkey" });
```

How can I make sure that the toggler is **hiding** the component (equivalent with the first line of code above) **and** that I can control the time for the process to be done (equivalent to the second line of code above)?

Comment: You can use $("#emailInvalid").hide(700)

Comment: @rishabhdev Hide **with** duration? I was under impression that it was depracated (as was *show*) to the benefit of *toggle* as of version 1.7 or 1.9 (or something like that)...

Comment: @KonradViltersten : would you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: @ParagBhayani Not certain if I follow. Would you like to see a fiddle for how the deprecated components work? Please advise.

Comment: You want to toggle the element from visible to invisible over a period of 0.7 seconds? With a fade between the visible (on) and invisible (off) states?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, but with a twist. I've been told that *toggle()* is most flexible in terms of the options that we can provide to it. At the moment I can't specify all the bells and whistles that I'm going to want in it, so in order not to limit myself, I want to do the things you asked about **but** with maximum flexibility, which I think is provided by *toggle()*.

Comment: I'd argue that the use of [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) would allow for more customisation, allowing for any CSS properties to be animated over a supplied duration with a callback function which runs on completion of the animation. Although there's a good chance that using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to use a CSS animation between a starting state (class 1) and finishing state (class 2) might be even more customisable. But without knowing precisely what you want to achieve it's difficult to offer generic advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - you can't.

Your options are to build something custom and carry out the logic in custom code. Alernatively, you might want to toggle between differen classes that have the look that you like. Check out [toggleAss()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for details.

For completeness I also give you a link to [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) as suggested by @DavidThomas, although I haven't used that one very much.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hehe, I missed that when I read his answer. I guess he was quick on *shift* but didn't reached *cl*. Or it's a reference to the *donkey* in my example. Good eyes, dude... Or maybe it's easy to see what one likes to see, hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Apply toggle only when visible:

```
 $('#donkey:visible').toggle(500);
```

Alternatively

```
   var element=$('#donkey');  
    if(element.css('display') !== 'none'){ 
    element.toggle(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want -- if the element (#donkey) is visible it gets hidden, if it's hidden nothing happens.

```
$( '#button' ).click( function(){
  if( $( '#donkey' ).css( 'display' ) === 'block' ) {
    $("#donkey").toggle( 700 );
  }
});
```

Codepen: http://s.codepen.io/SteveClason/debug/RRwpBd

Answer (score 0):

This small plugin would allow you to combine the two:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.myToggle = function(show, options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":hidden") ? show : !show) $(this).toggle(options);
    });
  };
}( jQuery ));
```

Simple example:

```
$("#donkey").myToggle(false, 700);
```